# Building Requirements-Specific Command For 'ffmpeg' Tool

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

Source Community

I've been trying to figure out an ffmpeg command with following requirements while converting 'avi' to 'mp4' with H264 video codecs. One command I tried was generic one like this which is recommended on most forums.

```
ffmpeg -I input.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

But this copies same video codec & doesn't convert to H264. Can anyone of you guys help me compose a line of code that would do the task with following requirements.

=> Video Options

Codec: H264
Video  Aspect  Ratio: No Change
Video  Resolution: No Change
Video  FPS: No Change

=> Audio Options

Codec: AC
Audio  Channels: No Change
Audio  Frequency: No Change
Audio  Normalization: No Change

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `-c:v libx264` ? (i.e. instead of `-c:v copy`, also `-c:v` is the same as `-vcodec`)

Comment: @grochmal thanks friend, I'll try this now & give my feedback to you soon.

Comment: @grochmal it didn't work really, says 'error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit-rate, rate, width or height'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us enumerate the parameters to `ffmpeg` then.

- `-acodec` is better written `-c:a` (menmonic codec for audio)
- `-vcodec` is better written `-c:v` (same mnemonic)
- `-i` is the input file (not `-I`)

`ffmpeg` does a pretty good guesswork based on file extensions, therefore doing:

```
ffmpeg -i file.wem file.mp4
```

Will convert things, but probably in a pretty poor quality.

---

For `H264` you are after the `libx264` codec therefore it should go:

```
ffmpeg -i file.avi -c:v libx264 -c:a copy file.mp4
```

As a test let's use the classic `webm` example:

```
$ wget http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm
...
$ ffmpeg -i big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm -c:a copy -c:v libx264 bbb.mp4
...
$ ffprobe bbb.mp4
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'bbb.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
  Duration: 00:00:32.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 414 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 341 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

And that looks promising, stream #0:0 is a H264 encoded video stream.